# paperclip: determining whether file has an extension in dynamic configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I originally had paperclip's default configuration contain

```
:url => "/some_path/:basename.:extension"
```

However, no all the files I'm uploading have extensions, and in those cases, I don't want the "." (between basename and extension in the configuration) to be there.  So I'd like to do something like this:

```
:url => lambda { |i| "/some_path/:basename#{".:extension" if i.extension}" }
```

I tried that and got a "can't convert Proc into String" error, which tells me that paperclip doesn't support dynamic configuration of urls the way it does for styles and processors.  Any ideas for how else I could do this, the less hack-ish the better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you replace

```
:basename.:extension
```

with

```
:filename
```

The more detailed answer is that basename, filename and extension are all interpolations, and you can use any interpolations defined in 'paperclip/interpolations' (in paperclip's lib directory) or define your own.

For example:

```
Paperclip.interpolates(:temperature) do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.city.temperature(:today)
end
```

assuming, of course, that the model that `has_attached_file` also `belongs_to :city` and that your city object knows today's temperature.